# Corona SDK, How to save String in leaderboards?

Tags: arrays, variables, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I'm having a problem with my leaderboards, the problem is my array score are all sorted in ascending order and works fine but I can't save the text beside the score? The situation is game.lua --> gameOver(Score & Difficulty Text) --> leaderboards(Score). Calling the variable from a table doesn't work.

leaderboards.lua

```
for i = 1, 10 do
    if (scoresTable[i]) then
      local yPos = 150 + (i * 130)

      local thisScore = display.newText(sceneGroup, scoresTable[i].. options.title,display.contentCenterX-30, yPos, font, 100)
      thisScore.anchorX = 0

    end
  end
```

game.lua

```
options{
  title = "Easy",
}
```

gameover.lua

```
options{
   title = options.title,
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean saving name of player to `leaderboard` variable?

Comment: typo its meant to be difficulty..

Comment: If there is a typo, please edit your question and fix it.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. What is your question or problem? What is the error message? What do you mean with "calling the variable from the table doesn't work" Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If your `leaderboard` is table with only scores like that

```
leaderboard = { 100, 200, 300 }
```

and you want also put string (difficulty level) in it along score. It can be done like that

```
leaderboard = { {100, "Easy"}, {200, "Hard"}, {300, "Easy"} }
```

Access to elements of `leaderboard`

```
leaderboard[1]     -> {100, "Easy"}
leaderboard[1][1]  -> 100
leaderboard[1][2]  -> "Easy"
```

Sorting table

```
function compare(a,b)
  return a[1] < b[1]
end

table.sort(leaderboard, compare)
```